# Catch "Cannot Find File"

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I have been searching for a while, but I cannot find the exception in PowerShell that would catch a "Cannot find file" error.

I would also like to have this loop until the user types in the correct file name to get.

```
# Ask user for file to read from
Try {
    $readFile = Read-Host "Name of file to read from: "
    $ips = GC $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$readFile.txt
}
Catch {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is a [non-terminating error](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/08/hey-scripting-guy-march-8-2010.aspx), and thus not caught. Add `-ErrorAction Stop` to your `Get-Content` statement or set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` and your code will work as you expect:

```
try {
  $readFile = Read-Host "Name of file to read from: "
  $ips = GC $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$readFile.txt -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use try/catch blocks for flow control. That is a generally-frowned-on practice, especially in PowerShell, since PowerShell's cmdlets will write errors instead of throwing exceptions. Usually, only non-PowerShell .NET objects will throw exceptions.

Instead, test if the file exists. That gives you much greater error control:

```
do
{
    $readFile = Read-Host "Name of file to read from: "
    $path = '{0}\Desktop\{1}.txt' -f $env:USERPROFILE,$readFile
    if( (Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Leaf) )
    {
        break
    }
    Write-Error -Message ('File ''{0}'' not found.' -f $path)
}
while( $true )
```